# Swift - Changing Scope Bar Tint Color

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I created a search controller with a scope bar programmatically and I couldn't change the scope bar's tint color. I created the search controller with the following code:

```
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Buildings or Codes"
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
definesPresentationContext = true
searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["Building Names", "Building Codes"]
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
```

There is also a cancel button for the search bar and I changed the tint color using this code:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf:[UISearchBar.self]).tintColor = UIColor.red
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let darkRed = UIColor(red: 0.392, green: 0.012, blue: 0.020, alpha: 1.00)
searchController.searchBar.tintColor = darkRed
```

[image: search scope red tint color]

Comment: That was much easier than I thought... Thank you so much!